# HTML in vuetify hints

Tags: vuetify.js

Previously (I thought?) it was possible to put HTML into vuetify hints but for me this is no longer working. For example, in one of my components I have:

```
<v-checkbox
   v-model="create"
   label="Nice label"
   persistent-hint
   hint="<span class=&quot;red--text&quot;>Red hint</span>"
/>
```

This hint used to display in red but now I see the full HTML code. Has something changed or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Seems to be working as expected in the latest version: https://codeply.com/p/Rj7UTvACyq

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply @Zim. My problem must be elsewhere as I think that I have the latest versions of everything installed. On the other hand, I am still confused because even though this works in your codeply it is not working in https://codepen.io/pen?template=YzzjyrP and it is filed as a bug with a slot workaround in https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/9647. I'll try using slots in my code.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the Vuetify forum, MajesticPotatoe pointed me towards the bug report https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/9647. This gave the following slots workaround, which works in my code:

```
<v-checkbox
   v-model="create"
   label="Nice label"
   persistent-hint
   hint="<span class=&quot;red--text&quot;>Red hint</span>"
>
<template v-slot:message="{ message, key }">
 <span v-html="message"></span>
</template>
</v-checkbox>
```

It seems that this used to work without slots before the patch https://github.com/haggys22/vuetify/commit/f0d5edd7ddf7e01ba057b7f3d14604199b6db68d was merged.

Comment: I think this should be the accepted answer, it has a link of the commit that introduced the change and provides a solution on how to make it work after the change was introduced.

Answer (score 3):

behaviour changed from 1.5.19 to 1.5.20

- 1.5.19 (and before) treats html tags as expected
- 1.5.20, 1.5.21 treat html tags as simple text

Answer (score 2):

'hint' is the 'string' type so you can't add HTML tags. Here is the screenshot from documentation: https://prnt.sc/qlag61

So, I think you can apply red color from CSS / SCSS using this class name '.v-messages__message' if you really need red color in hint.